# Executing Python code on UNIX

Tags: python, unix

I have written a Python program to analyse a set of files present in a given directory, i.e. it asks for a path then it goes into the path directory and find specified files, process them and produces an output file. However, every time I want to execute the program on a UNIX machine I have to write `python my_prog.py`. Also, to process a directory the program must be copied to the directory first, then executed.

I want to make it so that in UNIX I type `my_prog` inside any directory the program be executed, which means getting rid of copying the program file to target directory. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

Make your program executable with

```
chmod +x my_prog.py
```

put

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

(or a variation of this) at the top of your source file and place your my_prog.py script into a directory in your path (i.e., somewhere in the set of directories as usually defined by the `PATH` environment variable which is searched for commands to be executed).

Once your program is in your path, you will be able to execute it from anywhere, i.e., without having to place the program in your current directory or fully specifying the directory path to it.

You should be able to see the value of your current `PATH` environment variable in most shells with this command:

```
env | grep -i path
```

or

```
echo $PATH
```

Just in case, here is a bit more basic information on the PATH variable: http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cs348/unix_path.html and 
http://kb.iu.edu/data/acar.html. Google will yield many more. Hope
this helps.

Comment: but as i've told i just want to avoid copying the prog file to the directory in my path

Comment: Not your path as in your current working directory, your path as in the set of locations like `/usr/bin` that you can execute commands from. Copy it to one of those locations once, and you'll be able to run it anywehere.

Comment: @Marius is correct, and I appended some additional explanation to my original answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

As always, add a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line, make it [executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions), and copy it to a directory in `$PATH`.